# How to create table in widget.xml

Tags: magento2, widget, table

I wanna add a html table in widget.xml. 
I mean this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use CMS Static Block instead. Then you can create table on that specific Block

Comment: Yes that will be great but i wanna custom the widget, not the block :( because that's what my customer request.